# Problems with UPDATE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to give the most profitable employee in this lab a 9% raise.

I wrote this query to find the most profitable employee:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT SALESPERSONS.EmpID
  , SALESPERSONS.Ename
  , ((SUM(NVL(ORDERITEMS.Qty, 0) * NVL(INVENTORY.Price, 0)) - NVL(SALESPERSONS.Salary, 0))) AS Profit
FROM SALESPERSONS, ORDERS, ORDERITEMS, INVENTORY
WHERE SALESPERSONS.EmpID = ORDERS.EmpID (+)
AND ORDERS.OrderID = ORDERITEMS.OrderID (+)
AND ORDERITEMS.PartID = INVENTORY.PartID (+)
GROUP BY SALESPERSONS.EmpID
  , SALESPERSONS.Ename
  , SALESPERSONS.Salary
ORDER BY Profit DESC)
WHERE rownum = 1)
```

I've validated that that works (it's not a very big database so I was able to do this manually).

I then created an UPDATE statement to give this one employee a raise:

```
UPDATE SALESPERSONS
SET Salary = (
SELECT MAX(SALARY)+MAX(SALARY)*.09
FROM SALESPERSONS, (SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT SALESPERSONS.EmpID
  , SALESPERSONS.Ename
  , ((SUM(NVL(ORDERITEMS.Qty, 0) * NVL(INVENTORY.Price, 0)) - NVL(SALESPERSONS.Salary, 0))) AS Profit
FROM SALESPERSONS, ORDERS, ORDERITEMS, INVENTORY
WHERE SALESPERSONS.EmpID = ORDERS.EmpID (+)
AND ORDERS.OrderID = ORDERITEMS.OrderID (+)
AND ORDERITEMS.PartID = INVENTORY.PartID (+)
GROUP BY SALESPERSONS.EmpID
  , SALESPERSONS.Ename
  , SALESPERSONS.Salary
ORDER BY Profit DESC)
WHERE rownum = 1));
```

Which updates the salary for all eleven employees.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. My top query only returns one result.

Comment: Your `FROM SALESPERSONS, (SELECT *...)` creates Cartesian Product.

Comment: I wondered about that but this:

    <pre>FROM SALESPERSONS, (SELECT SALESPERSONS.Salary
    FROM (...<code>

returned the same results.

Comment: I know you say it's a small database but I wonder about the performance of this update query and its readability. It is interesting you reference multiple tables and use `WHERE` (implicit joins) clauses instead of `JOIN` (explicit joins) statements on IDs. See this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause).

Answer (score 0):

The below modification should work.

```
UPDATE SALESPERSONS
    SET Salary = (
    SELECT MAX(SALARY)+MAX(SALARY)*.09
    FROM SALESPERSONS WHERE
    EmpID in 
     (SELECT EmpID
    FROM (
    SELECT SALESPERSONS.EmpID
      , SALESPERSONS.Ename
      , ((SUM(NVL(ORDERITEMS.Qty, 0) * NVL(INVENTORY.Price, 0)) - NVL(SALESPERSONS.Salary, 0))) AS Profit
    FROM SALESPERSONS, ORDERS, ORDERITEMS, INVENTORY
    WHERE SALESPERSONS.EmpID = ORDERS.EmpID (+)
    AND ORDERS.OrderID = ORDERITEMS.OrderID (+)
    AND ORDERITEMS.PartID = INVENTORY.PartID (+)
    GROUP BY SALESPERSONS.EmpID
      , SALESPERSONS.Ename
      , SALESPERSONS.Salary
    ORDER BY Profit DESC)
    WHERE rownum = 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a `sql-server` guy but I think your `UPDATE` doesn't have a `WHERE`, so it updates every row in the table getting the salary for each row using the inner query.  You have to have a `WHERE` at the outer level that indicates which rows you want to update.

If this is a one-time query, you could just get the PK for the employee in question and use that in the `WHERE`.

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE SALESPERSONS
SET Salary = Salary+Salary*.09
WHERE EmpId=(
  SELECT TOP 1 SALESPERSONS.EmpID
FROM SALESPERSONS, ORDERS, ORDERITEMS, INVENTORY
WHERE SALESPERSONS.EmpID = ORDERS.EmpID
AND ORDERS.OrderID = ORDERITEMS.OrderID
AND ORDERITEMS.PartID = INVENTORY.PartID
GROUP BY SALESPERSONS.EmpID
  , SALESPERSONS.Ename
  , SALESPERSONS.Salary
ORDER BY Profit DESC);
```